# Ruby POST request with cookies?

Tags: ruby, cookies, curl

I have a Ruby script that sends a POST request with a cookie using:

```
curl.exe -H "Cookie: SomeCookie=#{cookie}" -d "SomaData=#{data}" http://somesite.com/post
```

I tried to rewrite this into native Ruby using Net::HTTP, but this code doesn't work:

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI('http://somesite.com/post'),
                {'SomeData' => '#{data}',
                'Cookie' => 'SomeCookie=#{cookie}'} )
```

How do I solve this problem?

I'am using MRI Ruby 1.9.3 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not look into using [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb)? It's a Ruby interface to libcurl, and has an interface that's closer to cURL than Net::HTTP.

This is from the documentation:

```
http = Curl.get("http://www.google.com/")
puts http.body_str

http = Curl.post("http://www.google.com/", {:foo => "bar"})
puts http.body_str

http = Curl.get("http://www.google.com/") do|http|
  http.headers['Cookie'] = 'foo=1;bar=2'
end
puts http.body_str
```

Comment: I cant install gem curb on windows, it cant find libcurl. But PATH is already has path to libcurl directory with curl.exe, libcurl.dll and another 6 dll's